# Change Character camera while in-game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

///Question : How to change the camera to the other player without it being buggy

So I have a piece of code which is  changing the variable selecterChar from 0 to 1 or reverse every time the user presses 'E'and it works great. This is in a different Script which I access in this one with this code

```
    private void ChangeCharacter()
{
    GameObject thePlayer = GameObject.Find("Walk (1)");
    PlayerMovement playerMovemnt = thePlayer.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
    int selectedCharacter = playerMovemnt.selectedChar;
    selCharacter = selectedCharacter;
}
```

Now the other part of this script is used for the camera. I want to change the camera with this

```
private void Start()
{

    offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    offset = transform.position - player2.transform.position;
}

private void LateUpdate()
{

    if (selCharacter == 0)
    {
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = player2.transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

So if the selCharacter (declared in the start of this script) is 0 the camera moves to player but if it is 1 then it goes to player2. So the ChangeCharacter method is used only 1 time when the game starts but if I move the code from ChangeCharacter() to lateUpdate() it works but is changing the camera multiple times before it stops and if it is in the ChangeCharacter() method and I call it from the LateUpdate() one it works only for the first player.

Comment: in this lines
 `offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    offset = transform.position - player2.transform.position;` you are overwriting the offset, do you want that?

Comment: I just fixed it with adding Down to GetKey in the other script and jsut adding the ChangeCharacter() code in the lateUpdate script. Now it is working and for the offset it was left behind from some tests. I just forgot to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)to Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)and then added this

```
    GameObject thePlayer = GameObject.Find("Walk (1)");
    PlayerMovement playerMovemnt = thePlayer.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
    int selectedCharacter = playerMovemnt.selectedChar;
    selCharacter = selectedCharacter;
```

to the Update method as i did not need the other one and it worked.

PS : Will check it as answered tomorrow.